# What is InstancePerLifetimeScope in Autofac?

Tags: autofac

Can someone please explain in plain English what the lines of code where I put the question marks do? Or maybe point me to an article that puts light on this. This code is for registering dependencies in an autofac container

```
var builder = new Autofac.ContainerBuilder();


builder.Register<NHibernateInstance>(c => 
    new NHibernateInstance(ConnString, false))
       .InstancePerDependency();//?????

builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<NHibernateInstance>()
    .GetFactory().OpenSession())
    .As<ISession>()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope(); //-----?????
```

Comment: That's called a `Method`. right click on it and select "Go To Definition" if you want to see what it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a dependency injection container. The `Autofac.ContainerBuilder` gets a new container, or registrar you might say.

The `builder.Register<NHibernateInstance>` is stating that when constructing an `NHibernateInstance` during the recovery phase (i.e. getting an instance out of the container) this is how it should be built.

The last line is indicating that when resolving an `NHibernateInstance` the `OpenSession` method should be called once per the lifetime of the object.